# errors on php and mysql after moving to php 7

Tags: php, mysql

I moved to a new server and now my script throws these errors:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /admin/classes/db_functionsClass.php on line 57
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error() in /admin/classes/db_functionsClass.php:57 Stack trace:\n#0 /admin/index.php(45): db_functionsClass->selectQuery('tbl_adminuser', 'where username=...')

This is line 57:

```
$this->result=mysqli_query($this->query) or die(mysql_error());
```

And line 45 from index file

```
$db->selectQuery($table,$condition);  // Executing Select Query.
```

And the whole function from db_function:

```
    function selectQuery($table,$condition,$fields="")
    {
        if(trim($fields)=="")
                $fields="*";
        $this->query="select $fields from $table $condition";
        $this->result=mysqli_query($this->query) or die(mysql_error());
        if($this->result)
        $this->num=mysql_num_rows($this->result);    
    }
```

Comment: don't mixup `mysql` and `mysqli`. Use the later one

Comment: The `query` function requires a connection and you can't use the `mysql_error` with `mysqli`. The `mysqli` error function also requires the connection.

Comment: `mysqli_query($this->query)` does't work in any version.

Comment: If i delete this " or die(mysql_error()) " it doesn't let me in no matter if the password is good

Comment: it was mysql_query before and it worked but now it has errors

Answer (score 0):

Look more carefully to article [mysqli::query mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
There are 2 forms object-oriented and procedural. Library needs to know on which DB connection issue commands. In OO case opened connection is holding inside object, while in procedural style you should pass it at  first param. Here you are trying to use procedural function mysqli_query in OO way. 
Try to rewrite `mysqli_query($this->query)` like procedural:
`mysqli_query($sql_link, $this->query)` 

or OO:
`$this->mysqli_object->query($this->query)`
Look to examples in manual!